# How can I mark properties required to show up different in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Let's say we have a class like so:

```
public class Plan
{
    public string PlanCode { get; set; } //Required
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SuccessUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make intellisense show required fields/properties different, such as italicized or a shade of red?

One would be able to determine what properties would be required quickly if calling a `Create()` method for instance.

Note: When I say show up different in intellisense I don't mean the tool-tip text that you see when the member is highlighted. I specifically mean the text of the member itself.

Comment: If it's something you're going to use regularly, I would consider writing an add-in for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe you can. You should design your objects with required fields in mind, i.e. constructors.

So any fields that the object requires should be parameters in a constructor.

```
public class Plan
{
    public string PlanCode { get; set; } //Required
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SuccessUrl { get; set; }

    public Plan(string planCode)
    {
        PlanCode = planCode;
    }
}
```

This is allows your code to clearly express its intention. Any developer using the Plan class will know that PlanCode is required, as it is enforced by the constructor.

Comment: I completely agree with you, but in my opinion it gets messy if the object has 12 properties and 8 are required. However, it doesn't seem like I have a choice.

Comment: Agreed, but maybe again, is that another design issue? When things get "messy" its usually a code smell :)